# Powershell 7-zip console output trace log modification

Tags: powershell, logging, zip, trace, 7zip

I am writing powershell script, which archives files into .zip . Also I added Transcript, which logs all build in 7-zip log. Question, is it possible to modify 7-zip console log? 
Example:

> 7-Zip 18.05 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2018-04-30
>
> Scanning the drive: 2 folders, 4 files, 635322 bytes (621 KiB)
>
> Creating archive: D:\folder\folder\file.zip
>
> Add new data to archive: 2 folders, 4 files, 635322 bytes (621 KiB)
>
> - folder\file.docx
> - folder\file.DOCX
> - folder\file.docx
> - folder\file.DOCX

Here is 7-zip line which is responsible to create zip and here I get all console log:

```
[array]$arguments = @("a", "-stl", "-y", "-bb1", "-bd", "-sdel", "-scsWin","-p$pass", $tempDestination, "$($tempProjectDir)\*" )
                    & $Zip $arguments | Out-String
```

Is it possible to edit console output, fox example delete this output:

> 7-Zip 18.05 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2018-04-30

Or

> Scanning the drive:
>   2 folders, 4 files, 635322 bytes (621 KiB)

With this I want to achieve better log file and to have only important information in log file.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the output to a `Where-Object` and use regular expressions to filter what you don't want. Like this:

```
[array]$arguments = @("a", "-stl", "-y", "-bb1", "-bd", "-sdel", "-scsWin","-p$pass", $tempDestination, "$($tempProjectDir)\*" )
& $Zip $arguments | 
    Out-String |
        Where-Object { $_ -notmatch 'Igor\ Pavlov|Scanning\ the\ drive:'}
```